# Display next posts when non previous

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a wordpress theme displaying the Next / Previous post but having some trouble when you're viewing the first post.

Obviously on the first post there are no other posts previous, however I would like to display the next post 2 posts

My current code looks like:

```
<?php next_post('%','', TRUE, '1'); ?>
<?php previous_post('%','', TRUE, '1'); ?>
```

Comment: you'll need to either edit one/both of the stock functions, or create your own functions to deal with more than +-1 post functionality (I would suggest writing your own functions so that they don't get overwritten on wp update)

Comment: Also keep in mind that the functions you posted are deprecated...

Comment: Do you want to display the posts like: 1, 2, 3… ?

Comment: I want to display post titles

Answer (score 2):

I usually get the current page and then apply a class to that page, I don't know if you can do this in wordpress.

```
// find the current page
$current_page = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
$class = '';
 if($current_page === 'index.php'){
   $class = ' hide'; //hide the previous link if the current page is index.php or the first page.
 }
<ol>
   <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><a href="somepage.php">prev</a></li>
   <li><a href="somepage.php">1</a></li>
   <li><a href="somepage.php">2</a></li>
 </ol>
```

also check this `php pagination` script on github [php paginator](https://github.com/phutis/php_paginator)

Answer (score 1):

Let'me try. You can check the position on the loop, to check if it is on beginning or in the end.

```
$firstPost=( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && !is_paged() );
$lastPost=( $wp_query->current_post == 0 && $wp_query->current_pos $wp->query->post_count-1 );
```

You can change something to get it better.